# Please Let me know mysql query: alias in where clause

Tags: mysql, syntax, alias

```
1. SELECT 
2.  (SELECT SUM(count) FROM _ERP_재고 as jego WHERE jego.goodsno=link.goodsno) as tt, 
3.  (SELECT catnm FROM gd_category WHERE category=LEFT(link.category, 3)) as cate1, 
4.  (SELECT catnm FROM gd_category WHERE category=LEFT(link.category, 6)) as cate2 
5. FROM gd_goods as goods, gd_goods_link as link, _ERP_재고 as jego 
6. WHERE link.goodsno=goods.goodsno 
7. AND jego.goodsno=link.goodsno 
8. AND (SELECT SUM(count) FROM _ERP_재고 as jego WHERE jego.goodsno=link.goodsno) > 0 
9. AND link.category LIKE '009%' GROUP BY goods.goodsno
```

I make an inappropriate query because the 2nd line is same as line 8.
If I replace the sub select in line 8 by `tt` (alias from line 2), an error occurs.
Please let me know how to get rid of calling the subquery a second time.

Comment: please provide database structure and the data you wish to receive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use alias names in `WHERE` clause. Instead you have to use `HAVING`.

```
1. SELECT 
2.  (SELECT SUM(count) FROM _ERP_재고 as jego WHERE jego.goodsno=link.goodsno) as tt, 
3.  (SELECT catnm FROM gd_category WHERE category=LEFT(link.category, 3)) as cate1, 
4.  (SELECT catnm FROM gd_category WHERE category=LEFT(link.category, 6)) as cate2 
5. FROM gd_goods as goods, gd_goods_link as link, _ERP_재고 as jego 
6. WHERE link.goodsno=goods.goodsno 
7. AND jego.goodsno=link.goodsno 
8. AND link.category LIKE '009%' GROUP BY goods.goodsno
9. HAVING tt > 0
```